# Importing C methods/classes into a C# project

Tags: c#, .net, c, cross-language

I have some c headers, and a c lib that I'd like to import and use in a c# project. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

Use `[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport]` attribute ([P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx)):

```
[DllImport("dllname.dll")]
static extern void MyFunctionName();
```

Comment: I don't have a dll, just a lib, and a few headers

Comment: You'll need to build that lib into a dll then.  You can't link the lib directly into your C# program that I'm aware of.

Comment: Can't you create a DLL from the lib in C? It's not possible to call static C libraries directly. You might also take a look at C++/CLI in that case.

Comment: I don't know, I didn't compile it. I suppose I could, and see what happens.

Comment: You may have to wrap it up in a dll.

Answer (score 2):

What Mehrdad said.

Additionally, welcome to the wonderful world of marshalling.   [P/Invoke.Net](http://www.pinvoke.net/) is your new best friend.